How can I add and subtract to a variable from multiple game objects without losing the accuracy?
I have more than 100(close to 200) enemy game objects in my scene and 5-6 being spawned every second. I'm using object pooling and the objects are not being instantiated every time but only when needed.
I'm trying to record the stats where I can show total enemies remaining and total enemies taken down.
A simple mathematical function of addition and subtraction from respective game objects is not adding up to what it should be.
For example:
Total enemies spawned 200 (when I didn't kill a single one)
I kill a lot of enemies in an instant but when I'm done killing them all, enemies remaining is not always zero.
I tried killing the enemies one by one as they spawn and the addition and subtraction adds up correctly.
So how can I add and subtract to a variable from multiple game objects without loosing the accuracy?
    public void TookDownEnemy(int enemiesTookDown)
    {
        //enemiesAlive -= enemiesTookDown;
        enemiesTakenDown += enemiesTookDown;

        Debug.Log("stats, enemies took down: " + enemiesTakenDown);
        UpdateStats();

    }

    public void SpawnedNewEnemy(int spawned)
    {
        enemiesAlive += spawned;
        UpdateStats();


    }

    public void UpdateStats()
    {
        enemiesTakenDownText.text = ": " + enemiesTakenDown.ToString();
        enemiesAliveText.text = ": " + (enemiesAlive - enemiesTakenDown).ToString();
    }

I'm calling SpawnedNewEnemy from a an enemy spawning game object everytime it spawns a new enemy, TookDownEnemy gets called from the gameobject when they are spawned.
    public void InstantiateNewEnemy()
    {

        StatsManager.Instance.SpawnedNewEnemy(1);

        Enemy instance = ObjectPooler.DequeueObject<Enemy>("Enemy");

        instance.Initialize(10.0f); // get this hp value from the experience manager

        instance.SetThisAlive();

        instance.gameObject.SetActive(true);

        instance.transform.SetParent(enemiesHolder);

        int randomIndex = Random.Range(0, enemySpawnPoints.childCount);

        instance.transform.position = enemySpawnPoints.GetChild(randomIndex).position;

        instance.transform.rotation = Quaternion.identity;
    }


In a similar way when enemy is killed or dies
if(hp <= 0 && !isDead)
{
    //Destroy(this.gameObject); // use pooling here
    isDead = true;

    StatsManager.Instance.TookDownEnemy(1);

    this.GetComponent<Animator>().Play("playDead");

    Invoke("EnqueueGameObject", 0.25f);

}

Instead of directly adding and subtracting from a variable I made three different variables.

enemiesSpawned
enemiesTookDown
enemiesRemaining

where enemiesRemaining = enemiesSpawned - enemiesTookDown
Even this is having a discrepancy.
I'm assuming there should be a way to queue the addition and subtraction operation rather than just doing it.
UPDATE:
I tried doing it by queuing the addition and subtraction operations and execute those operations at a defined interval.
   public void TookDownEnemy(int enemiesTookDown)
   {
       enemiesTookDownQueue.Enqueue(enemiesTookDown);

   }

   public void SpawnedNewEnemy(int spawned)
   {
       enemiesAliveQueue.Enqueue(spawned);

   }


Now I've also limited the spawning of enemies to 260(based on time I'm spawning a total of 260 enemies). When using Queue to add and subtract I'm sumhow(pun intended) always ending up with a difference of 80.
Where 80 enemies remaining and I took down 180.
Here's how I'm adding those numbers up every 2 second.
   public void UpdateStats()
   {

       while(enemiesAliveQueue.Count > 0)
       {
           enemiesAlive += (int)enemiesAliveQueue.Dequeue();
       }

       while(enemiesTookDownQueue.Count > 0)
       {
           enemiesTakenDown += (int)enemiesTookDownQueue.Dequeue();
       }


       enemiesTakenDownText.text = ": " + enemiesTakenDown.ToString();
       coinsCollectedText.text = ": " + coinsCollected.ToString();
       enemiesAliveText.text = ": " + (enemiesAlive - enemiesTakenDown).ToString();
   }


Do you still have this problem if you don't use object pooling?

Are your re-spawned enemies coming back to life properly?

@shingo Yes the problem remains without pooling as well. Only when I'm killing the enemies one by one it works as expected.

@Jay Yes, I'm executing a function that sets them as not dead and update their health points. Please note that in this particular example where I have 260 enemies, the enemies were not killed at all, so the problem is definitely not coming from re-spawning them.

It seems odd to me you are passing in the number destroyed/spawned in these functions - should that not always be 1, could there be somewhere its >1 incorrectly

@Jay Apologies for the confusion it might be causing. It is because of a work around I was working on which will merge enemies into a single unit, so that one single enemy would pass in a value which is basically the number of enemies that merged into it.

You need to show "one" code example. Right now, you're updating the same variables in multiple places (going by the various code samples).

@GerrySchmitz I'm sorry I don't follow what you meant by "one" code sample. To clarify a bit from what I'm getting, there a static class "StatsManager" where I have two function in question here, which are "TookDownEnemy" and "SpawnedNewEnemy". Now these functions are being called from objects of enemy class when a certain condition is met as described in question.  The issue is likely because of "Race condition" as someone who answered said it. I'm still trying to figure it out and will update if I come across a concrete solution.

I'm refering to the following lines from your various "code fragments"; it implies you're at least "double counting": enemiesTakenDown += enemiesTookDown;
enemiesAlive += spawned;
enemiesAlive += (int)enemiesAliveQueue.Dequeue();
enemiesTakenDown += (int)enemiesTookDownQueue.Dequeue();

I do "counts"; I have static classes; with static (public get; private set) "counters"; and static methods for accessing those counters; so there is "no" chance of something "unknown" counting. And if I don't use "methods", then I use "setters"; so I can at least add break points or debug asserts.

I'm using a similar strategy as well but didn't make the the methods static only an instance was static. Anyway I did manage to solve the issue by using UnityEngine.Pool instead of my own implementation of ObjectPool. I'm still not sure why the inconsistency was coming with that but I guess Unity created their own way for handling such issues only.  Updating the question with the solution.

So I did manage to solve the issue but still don't know why the inconsistency was being caused.
Previously I was using my own implementation of Object Pool by following a YouTube video in which a generic class was created to create pools which can then be accessed as needed. It works as expected but it is more of a C# solution than a Unity solution to object pooling.
public static void EnqueueObject<T>(T item, string name) where T : Component
{
    if (!item.gameObject.activeSelf)
    {
        return;
    }

    item.transform.position = Vector2.zero;

    poolDictionary[name].Enqueue(item);

    Debug.Log("item.GetType(): " + item.GetType());

    item.gameObject.SetActive(false);

}

public static T DequeueObject<T>(string key) where T : Component
{
    if (poolDictionary[key].TryDequeue(out var item))
    {
        return (T)item;
    }

    return (T)EnqueueNewInstance(poolLookup[key], key);
    //return (T)poolDictionary[key].Dequeue();
}

public static T EnqueueNewInstance<T>(T item, string key) where T : Component
{
    T newInstance = Object.Instantiate(item);
    newInstance.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    newInstance.transform.position = Vector2.zero;
    poolDictionary[key].Enqueue(newInstance);
    return newInstance;
}

Turns out the right way to pool objects in Unity is to use UnityEngine.Pool instead. I followed this tutorial which was essentially doing the same thing but this time I don't have to worry about the queue.
I added these to my EnemySpawner.cs,
private void Start()
{
    _enemyPool = new ObjectPool<Enemy>(() =>
    {
        return Instantiate(enemyPrefab);
    }, enemy =>
    {
        enemy.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }, enemy =>
    {
        enemy.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }, enemy =>
    {
        Destroy(enemy.gameObject);
    }, false, 10, 20);

}

public void KillEnemy(Enemy enemy)
{
    _enemyPool.Release(enemy);
}

public void InstantiateNewEnemy()
{

    StatsManager.Instance.SpawnedNewEnemy(1);

    Enemy instance = _enemyPool.Get();

    instance.Initialize(10.0f); // get this hp value from the experience manager

    instance.SetThisAlive();

    instance.gameObject.SetActive(true);

    instance.transform.SetParent(enemiesHolder);

    int randomIndex = Random.Range(0, enemySpawnPoints.childCount);

    instance.transform.position = enemySpawnPoints.GetChild(randomIndex).position;

    instance.transform.rotation = Quaternion.identity;
}

Then when an enemy is killed
public void KillMyself()
{
    StatsManager.Instance.TookDownEnemy(1);
    EnemySpawner.Instance.KillEnemy(this);
}


(originally posted as an edit to the question by OP, rather than as an answer)
